# How to build a database schema in sql fiddle?

Tags: sqlfiddle

I tried using the text dll but i'm getting this message"

Unable to find consistent column separator in header row

I viewed their sample file but its not clear how to create and insert values in the database

Is it k to copy our create code in text dll box...

can any one help me....

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when getting data out of SQL server, if you have any kind of convert or cast functions in your select statement and don't specify a column name then this error is triggered when pasting data into SQL fiddle text to DDL. (No column name) will show up unless you alias your column name after the convert/cast by using:

```
AS 'Your Column Name'
```

Example:

```
CONVERT(date, Dt_Approv) AS Dt_Approv
```

This gets rid of the (No column name) in the DDL that causes the error.  It is at least something to try, it worked for me.

EDIT:

Not sure if I answered you the way you were hoping. To use the text to DDL tool on SQL Fiddle, all you have to do is paste in the tabular data from your databse or spreadsheet. From that the program will build the DDL, hence text to DDL  :)

No need for create or insert statements when using text to DDL, it will write them for you.